# Which of the following jumbled word is not a animal

Tags: anagram

This question was asked in mock test of an exam for which I am preparing.

> Which of the following jumbled word is not a animal?

LATHPEEN

FEFEOC

<sub>I originally had the wrong set of letters for the second jumbled word here, sorry for the inconvenience.</sub>

I have done other 2 options (which were there but I didn't wrote them here as I solved them) but I have no idea about these 2 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First word is

> Elephant

and second one is

> Coffee

Answer (score 0):

The top word can be solved as

> ELEPHANT

And the bottom word can be solved as

> CRICKET

Therefore, both are viable solutions when unscrambled.

Comment: I am not sure how one of these is not supposed to be an animal... is it possible that this is not a simple question but there is some deduction to be done? In this case, we would need to see the complete question.

Comment: You did edit this after my answer just to add to include it...

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I was editing my response while your answer was posted, so when I was finished your answer was here...